# Not able to update events title in angular calendar

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, rendering, angular-calendar

I tried to get the single event from events and then update the values. Even if I can update the values like title and color the update only shows in the onclick modal but I wanted to use my actual event on the calender to get the value updated.
And even after I close the modal I can see the updated value whenever I check in the console title.value. I know that this value isnt being able to assign to the event.title ..

And the reason its probably happening because

```
eventClicked({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void {
    console.log('Event clicked', event.title);
      let title = event.title;
      let color = event.color.secondary
    this.profileForm.patchValue({
      title: title,
      color: color
    })
    
    this.openPopup()
   
   
  }
```

but I am not getting any idea how can i update the values in events.

here's the modal block created using form

```
 <form [formGroup]="profileForm">
      <div 
      class="modal"
      tabindex="-1"
      role="dialog"
      [ngStyle]="{'display':displayStyle}">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4>All Events</h4>
          
          
         
              <div class="titleBlock">
                  <input
                  type="text"
                  id="title"
                  class="form-control"
                  formControlName="title"
                  [value]="input.value"
                  [(ngModel)]="input.value"
                  #input
                />
                <input
                type="color"
                class="form-control"
                formControlName="color"
             
              />
              
                 <!-- <span><i class="bi bi-check2 done" (click)="deleteEvent(event)" ></i></span> -->
       
                    
                
            </div>
     
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One Stop Solution for all CS problems</p>
      
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
                    (click)="closePopup()">
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>

Heres the app componenet ts file

    export class AppComponent {
  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    title: [''],
    color: [''],
  });
  // @ViewChild('modalContent', { static: true })
  // modalContent!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('modalContent', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) modalContent: ViewContainerRef;

 
  modalData: {
    action: string;
    event: CalendarEvent;
  };

  @Output() eventDelete: EventEmitter<CalendarEvent> = new EventEmitter();
  refresh = new Subject<void>();
  viewDate: Date = new Date();
  view: CalendarView = CalendarView.Month;
  CalendarView = CalendarView;
  getevent: string;
  getcolor: string;
  setView(view: CalendarView) {
    this.view = view;
  }
 
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  events: CalendarEvent[] = [
    {
    
      start: subDays(startOfDay(new Date()), 1),
      end: addDays(new Date(), 1),
      title: '111 An event with no end date',
      color:colors.red
    
      
    },
    {
      start: startOfDay(new Date()),
      end: addDays(new Date(), 2),
      title: '22 An event with 2',
      color:colors.blue
      
    },
    {
      start: subDays(startOfDay(new Date()), 3),
      end: addDays(new Date(), 3),
      title: '333 An event with no end date',
      color:colors.yellow
      
    },

  ]
  
  eventTimesChanged({
    event,
    newStart,
    newEnd,
  }: CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent): void {
    this.events = this.events.map((iEvent) => {
      if (iEvent === event) {
        return {
          ...event,
          start: newStart,
          end: newEnd,
        };
      }
      return iEvent;
    });
    this.handleEvent('Dropped or resized', event);
  }
 
  handleEvent(action: string, event: CalendarEvent): void {
    this.modalData = { event, action };
    
    //this.modal.open(this.modalContent, { size: 'lg' });
    this.openPopup() 
  }


  dayClicked({ date, events }: { date: Date; events: CalendarEvent[] }): void {
    console.log(date);
    this.view = CalendarView.Day;
    
  }

  eventClicked({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void {
    console.log('Event clicked', event.title);
      let title = event.title;
      let color = event.color.primary
    this.profileForm.patchValue({
      title: title,
      color: color
    })
  
    this.openPopup()
   
   
  }


  
  deleteEvent(eventToDelete: CalendarEvent) {
    this.events = this.events.filter((event) => event !== eventToDelete);
    console.log("Event deleted");
  }
  displayStyle = "none";
  
  openPopup() {
    this.displayStyle = "block";
  }
  closePopup() {
    this.displayStyle = "none";
  }

}
```

Another way I can get all the datas but it comes with all the events in a day.
if i use ngmodal instead of forms
hers the code.

```
<ng-container #modalContent >
  <div 
  class="modal"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  [ngStyle]="{'display':displayStyle}">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>All Events</h4>
      
      
        <div *ngFor="let event of events">
          <div class="titleBlock">
              <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              [(ngModel)]="event.title"
              (keyup)="refresh.next()"
            />
            <input
            type="color"
            [(ngModel)]="event.color.secondary"
            (change)="refresh.next()"
          />
          
              <span><i class="bi bi-check2 done" (click)="deleteEvent(event)" ></i></span> 
          </div>
                
            
        </div>
 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One Stop Solution for all CS problems</p>
  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
                (click)="closePopup()">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

it works perfectly but as you can see its using a for loop it. so when I click on it its going to show all the events. but I wanted a single event to come into pop up.

Comment: When you use ReactiveForms, in the input tag **only** use `formControlName` (or `[formControl]`. Believe me, when you use in the same tag `[value]`, `[(ngModel)]` and `formControlName` a little cat die :|

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo. But Theres a defualt value given in the json data as you can see for event. I wanted the input to have the previous data. whenever I click it.. then I can update it.  and thats why I tried various things like value, ngmodel, through which I can get the data but they arent enough to store the updated data I guess.. or some logical mistakes I probably did here.